# How to correct a sesssion_write_close() warning?

Tags: joomla-3.x, session

I have the following error shown on error log. But I am a Joomla novice. Could I get a simple step by step guide on how to solve my WSOD problem here?

> [10-Nov-2018 07:48:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user).
> Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70) in /home/mydir/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 194

Answer (score 0):

This warning is caused by a server misconfiguration. You should consult with your web host (open a support ticket) where your site is hosted. They can help you to solve this problem. This is not a Joomla error. (on the top of that, we do not know, which version of Joomla, version of PHP and so on... your host will know these)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Joomla application doesn't have the right permissions to your session's save_path folder. You can get the session's save_path by using `phpinfo()`. You should ensure that the Linux user powering your Joomla website has permissions to read and write from that folder.